# System.Runtime.Remoting not present in COM reference pop up

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have just started with .net development. But while working with my first project for remoting I stucked on an error for an import present in my project.

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels
```

Gives an error showing 'The type or namespace name 'Channels' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Remoting.' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'

And after searching a lot on web I got solution to add COM reference to the project with dll named System.Runtime.Remoting but on the pop of add reference I couldn't found the dll. Do I have to download the same or any other solution for that?

Comment: I don't have a direct explanation but want to point out that the remoting paradigm has been deprecated for years.

Comment: No, don't try it with a COM reference.  Remoting support was removed in .NET Core (aka .NET 5+).  Microsoft recommends gRPC as an alternative.  Or use a legacy project template, the ones that have ".NET Framework" in their name.